# Help Please with Static IP

Tags: static-ip, wireless-access-point

Ubuntu Community 
I have this situation MY ISP send to me Static IP 75.108.xxx.xxx and i need to access my server from the outside of my network i"m use Google DNS 208.180.42.68 and 208.180.42.100
i followed all the Instruction i found  in the net bit still can not access my VPs from Putty or any other way so help please
here my setup

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface  
# auto enp4s0
# iface enp4s0 inet dhcp

# Static IP Address Assignment
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
address 209.33.xx.xx
subnet 255.255.255.0
gateway 209.33.xx.x
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: We'll probably need more information to determine the issue, but for starters, do you have port forwarding setup on your router? You may have the static IP address from your ISP but that just means you can hit the very outside of your network and it may not know where to go from there until you configure your router to send SSH traffic to your server.

Comment: Why are you assigning `209.33.xx.xx` when you mention that your assigned IP address is `75.108.xxx.xxx`?

Comment: And what is your network layout? Typically in residential settings you have a NAT gateway with a public IP.